# Is it OK to style anchor tags as block elements?

Tags: html, css, anchor, block

Is it OK to use the HTML below to style an anchor as a block element? I read somewhere before that it's wrong, but I can't see why and it's so damn convenient! What are the drawbacks of this method, if any?

```
<style>
a.button{
display:inline-block;
padding: 10px 20px;
border: 1px solid grey;
}
</style>

<a class="button" href="#link">Click me!</a>
```

Comment: It's perfectly fine.

Comment: it's perfectly fine to use inline-block.

Comment: @MrLister Is there an issue with styling just as block?

Comment: @silkfield No, it's just that your question title says "block" while the code has "inline-block", as if they are interchangeable, while they are really very different things. That's all. There are no problems with using either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not only is it perfectly OK for `<a>` elements to be styled as blocks or inline-blocks, it's actually necessary in some cases, to avoid certain problems.
Take this bit of code:

```css
a {outline:1px dotted}
```

```html
Click <a href="#"><div>here</div></a>
```

In some browsers, the outline around the anchor is not a proper rectangular shape, because of the div inside. In others, the outline isn't even there at all. If you also change the a's display to `block`, the differences go away; it has a nice rectangular outline in all browsers.

```css
a {outline:1px dotted; display:block}
```

```html
Click <a href="#"><div>here</div></a>
```

So, no need to worry.